# Dynamically Stretching JRDesignTextField in Horizontal direction

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReport API to generate my reports dynamically. I am using JRDesignTextField class. There is a method of this class setStretchWithOverflow(boolean). Set its parameter to true if we want the text field should stretch vertically if its text does not fit in one line.

But What should i do when i want to stretch my field horizontally dynamically. 
Thanks.